# JavaFX Change text under Progress Indicator (default: Done)

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, progress-bar, javafx-8

how can I change default text "Done" under ProgressIndicator in JavaFX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky but it is possible:

In **JavaFX 2.2** this is made like this:

```
ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
ProgressIndicatorSkin indicatorSkin = new ProgressIndicatorSkin(indicator);
final Text text = (Text) indicatorSkin.lookup(".percentage");
indicator.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number newValue) {
        // If progress is 100% then show Text
        if (newValue.doubleValue() >= 1) {
            // This text replaces "Done"
            text.setText("Foo");
        }
    }
});
indicator.skinProperty().set(indicatorSkin);
indicator.setProgress(1);
```

In **JavaFX 8** you must first call `applyCss()` before doing a lookup and you do not need the skin anymore:

```
ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
indicator.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number newValue) {
        // If progress is 100% then show Text
        if (newValue.doubleValue() >= 1) {
            // Apply CSS so you can lookup the text
            indicator.applyCss();
            Text text = (Text) indicator.lookup(".text.percentage");
            // This text replaces "Done"
            text.setText("Foo");
        }
    }
});
indicator.setProgress(1);
```

Change the text "Foo" to your finished Text and you are ready

I have tested this code and it should work fine. ;-)

Comment: @Kalashchni This code does not seem to work anymore(?). I mean I am using the latest JavaFx 8 and the ProgressIndicatorSkin doesn't have a lookup()-method? Anyway to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: Well I just noticed that there's a private field "doneText" in the ProgressIndicatorSkin-class, which I can access with a little bit of reflection.

Comment: Then again.. it's a private static final field, and I cannot seem to be able to change it.. I suppose there's an easier way to change it nowadays?

Comment: added answer for javafx-8 ;-)