# change the text under the ProgressIndicator

Tags: javafx-8

I want to change the text under the ProgressIndicator. The question was asked but with javaFx new version, the suggested solution [JavaFX Change text under Progress Indicator (default: Done)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972387/javafx-change-text-under-progress-indicator-default-done) does not work anymore.

Could we get the component instead of the css which changing every time !

Comment: please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: It's resolved with the new JDK